# IE is not display an HTML page for certain users

Tags: html, internet-explorer, amazon-s3

I am trying to get ideas for what is happening here.
I have deployed a page onto amazon S3. Here is a test page I put together for this question

http://static.a2om.com.s3.amazonaws.com/shelltrainers/html/short_test.html

However, my client see's THIS!

[image]

She is using IE9.

Any ideas?

We have looked into/thought about
- GZIP problems
- Encoding problems

As I said, S3 probably has somthing to do with it, but we can not reproduce the problem ourselves :(

MORE INFO 02/JUNE

We have identified that the gibberish is basically compressed (GZIP) HTML. The browser on this clients machine is not picking up that its GZIP or the header so displaying that rubbish.

This is only happening on her "VPN" tunnel, so, perhaps the VPN has something to do with it?

If the files are uploaded uncompressed, its fine.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do you know any more users having this problem? I can't reproduce it either... Only thing i can think of is that here IE if f****d up ( maybe an [profile reset](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1222-internet-explorer-reset.html) will help out...)

Comment: @Mathlight no other users have reported problems yet. Its a large corporate and I am asking the client to check with her colleagues